# Using systemd to execute a script before system shutdown?

Tags: systemd, shutdown

I wrote a script that suspends all my VirtualBox machines, and put a line in `/etc/rc.local.shutdown`, but it doesn't seem to work,

`su - XX -c /XX`

When I'm booting the next time, VirtualBox tells me the machine was  `Aborted`, so the script wasn't executed. (Launching that script manually works for me)

P.S I already enabled `shutdown.target`

**EDIT**

The problem seems more complicated than I thought, in my `.bashrc`, if it's running on `tty3`, it executes `startx`, so when systemd decide to shutdown/reboot, it whould kill `VBoxSVC` process and other stuff when X Session dies.

I also tried to hack the source code of `xfsm-shutdown-helper`, make a fake `systemctl` that  execute my script first, none of the above works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many VMs are you shutting down in tandem? .. Unrelated to your question, but I believe I've found an issue in VirtualBox 4.2.6 where shutting down too many at once (5 to 10) (all are linked-clones from a shared VM) leads to corrupted cloned VMs.

Comment: @adamrmcd I'm shutting down one-by-one...

Comment: Do you want to suspend the VMs rather than shutting them down? In a classic (SysV?) init-based system, you should be able to do that from inittab / by modifying the scripts for the runlevel used for shutdown... (read the init man page, it differs between unixes, possibly between Linux distributions as well)

Comment: You might also want to echo something to a logfile from the script, to be sure that it actually didn't run, rather than just failed as a result of something else...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg the script works fine if I call it with root directly ... and I start to think the VBOX process might just be killed by the shutdown process

Comment: Ok, I think I might realise something here... You have a box, that you want to shut down, but before you shut it down, you want to suspend all the Virtualbox VMs running on it? (Rather than doing weird things on a guest running in Virtualbox...) RC scripts would be the normal way to do it... Not sure if systemd messes that up...

Comment: If ti supports SysV style init scripts, you would add a script like `/etc/init.d/stopvms` that stop the VMs when passed a "stop" parameter. You then create links (symbolic or hard) to that script as say `/etc/rc5.d/K01stopvms` and `/etc/rc3.s/K01stopvms` . (the scripts in the directories are run in order (K* when leaving a runlevel, S* when entering a runlevel)) (You should also be able to do it as "start" scripts in runlevels 0 (shutdowns) and 6 (reboots))

Comment: rc.local won't do anything in a systemd environment, because systemd doesn't use rc.local.

Comment: @Rob I created a compatible systemd service for it .. but seems problem wasn't much complicated than I thought

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to suspend your VB machines before your bash session on tty3 terminates, or before your Xserver terminates.

I believe systemd is unaware of your running Xsession, because you start it from your .bashrc, so it will be difficult to tell systemd to suspend your VBs before it terminates your shell or your Xsession. You will have to find a place in the shutdown sequence which is "early enough", which might be difficult to find and semantically questionable, because it would mix "user stuff" with "system stuff"

The solutions may somewhat depend on how systemd terminates your processes, but the following should at least point in a good direction:

**Before the shell terminates**

```
suspendVB() {
        echo "suspending VBs"
        # put real code here
        exit
}

trap suspendVB EXIT
```

If you make this the rcfile of your bash (or add it to .bashrc), then the code in `suspendVB()` will be executed before the shell terminates. You can test this by running

```
bash --rcfile xxx
```

where the file `xxx` contains the code from above. This starts another shell inside your current shell, just for testing. When you then run a simple exit, you will see:

```
martin@beaureve:~$ exit
exit
suspending VBs
/home/martin >
```

and you are back in your original (login) shell.

You may have to find out how systemd actually terminates your login shells, and you may have to replace `EXIT` by some other signal(s). Lookup the `trap` command to find out more.

Note that When systemd kills your processes with "-9" (SIGKILL) then you will not be able to trap the termination, i.e. you're out of luck.

**Before the Xsession terminates**

Alternatively you may try a similar thing with your Xsession. This is essential in cases where systemd terminates your Xsession *before* it terminates your shells. You may want to insert a trap in one of the X startup files (e.g. .xinitrc) - lookup the man pages for `startx` and `xinit` to find out more.

If your `startx` file looks something like mine, then the xserver is started in foreground and you can alternatively simply place your suspend commands after the line where X is actually started (and not use traps at all):

```
xinit "$client" $clientargs -- "$server" $display $serverargs
retval=$?
echo " --- suspending VBs ---"
```

I put in the line saying "suspending VBs" and when I run `startx -- vt8` I get a fullblows (kde) session on vt8 and only when I logout, the line "suspending VBs" appears on the screen.